# Conexão com WebService SOAP WSDL

Tags: php, web-service, soapclient

Estou tentando receber um xml de um Webservice soap wsdl. Com o código abaixo eu consigo dar um get em seus métodos.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php?wsdl');

$result = $client->__getFunctions();

print_r($result);
```

O retorno é: `Array ( [0] => string getCNPJ(string $token, string $cnpj) )`

Porém ao tentar acessar o método `getCNPJ`

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php?wsdl');

$result = $client->getCNPJ($token, $cnpj);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

print_r($xml);
```

recebo uma exceção:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception:

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema seguindo o tutorial [Chamando um WebService SOAP com PHP](https://thiagovespa.com.br/blog/2012/05/31/chamando-um-webservice-soap-com-php/)

**Ficou assim:**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php?wsdl');

$function = 'getCNPJ';

$arguments= array(
    'token' => $token,
    'cnpj'  => $cnpj
);

$options = array('location' => 'http://www.roveri.inf.br/ws/cnpj.php');


$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

echo 'Response: ';

print_r($result);
```